# Paypal Donation button doesn't work

Tags: forms, button, paypal, paypal-buttons

It works fine for me using chrome, and a buddy using FF says it works as well. Doesn't work on IE at all. All I did was copy / paste the button code from paypal and put it into my footer. Page I'm getting says: Error Detected; Some required information is missing or incomplete. Please correct your entries and try again. Help?

```
<div style="
width: 145px;
margin: 0 auto;
"><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" style="
padding-top:30px;
padding-left:30px;
">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is related to PayPal button code protection.
By default PayPal button code has a hidden field named *encrypted* that contains all information about payment in encrypted form.
When *Remove code protection* link (located above textarea with button code in PayPal button generation page) is clicked different code, containing many fields in plain-text form is displayed.

I have faced situation where protected (encrypted) code had this issue, but unprotected code worked without any issues. **NB** Using unprotected code may result in decreased security - by modifying unprotected button code users can make payments with changed currency, purpose or reference ID. Besides spambots can easily pick up e-mail from unprotected button code if email address is used instead of secure merchant ID. Also it is recommended to ask PayPal support for other possible issues that may arise from using unprotected code.

Comment: Looks like now protected (encrypted) code is also working fine.